# Laravel : I want to calculate total timing for punchin and punch out and generate total time

Tags: sql, database, laravel, vue.js

[image]

This is my database I want to calculate time difference between each **punch_in** and **punch_out** and calculate all total time for each day.

```
    $punch = punches::where('user_id','=',$user->id )->whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString())->get();       
    $punch_in = punches::where('user_id','=',$user->id )->whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString())->where('punch_in','!=',null)->get(); 
    $punch_out = punches::where('user_id','=',$user->id )->whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString())->where('punch_out','!=',null)->get();
```

This is the query that I have been using right now need any suggestion for It

Comment: Text, not images of text please. It is preferred if you add your table description, sample data  etc as text and not images to your question. Not only is it much easier to read but if someone wants to help you then they can easily copy data and use when testing their query.

Comment: ohk sure will take care of it

Comment: @dhairyapatel what kind of suggestion you need?

Comment: Place can you add the code for your `punches` model?

Comment: You could order by user and then by punch_in and then by punch_out and using that you can calculate the difference between two consequtive results given they belong to a single user and one is punch_in and the other is punch_out. This is my suggestion. If you want help coding it I suggest you make an attempt yourself first and if you are stuck you can update your question with actual code of your attempt and we can help you sort it out.

Comment: Already getting all the punch_in and punch_out data of each and every user but the thing is how can I sum up total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you simply use [`Carbon\Carbon`](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) in combination with [Accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) for this issue, like this:

Presuming you write something like this in your `App\Punch` model:

```php
protected $dates = [
    'punch_in', 
    'punch_out'
];

public function user(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function getTimingAttribute(): int
{
   if ($this->punch_out) {
       return $this->punch_out->diffInSeconds($this->punch_in);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

And this then in your `App\User` model:

```php
public function punches(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Punch::class);
}


public function getTotalTimingAttribute(): int
{
     return $this->punches ? $this->punches->reduce(function ($total, Punch $punch) {
         return $total + $punch->timing;
     }, 0) : 0;
}
```

In your `App\Http\Controllers\User` controller you get it like this:

```php
public function totalTiming(User $user)
{
    return $user->totalTiming;
}
```

I didn't test the code above so it might not work from the get go, but you get the idea.

Comment: How can I represent total in controller

Comment: Simple, like this `$user->totalTiming;`. Check my edit.

Comment: Call to a member function reduce() on null Giving this error

Comment: Yes just as above

Comment: So `$user->punches;` gives you `null`?

Comment: Yes its sending null

Comment: Ok, try selecting a user that has punches then, like `User::find(1)->punches` which according to your database should have punches.

Comment: Same output null

Comment: OK, but if `User::find(1)->punches` is `null` then the `HasMany` relation to the `App\Punch` model is wrong. That's all I can tell your from here on forth.

Comment: Maybe try and manually set the keys, dunno. Check the manual https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Call to undefined method App\punches::reduce() can you help in this

Comment: The `reduce` method should be called on a `Collection` object instance. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-reduce

Comment: Can you show an example that would be very helpfull as I'm new in laravel